# what is the equivalent of ".tickCenterLabel(true);" in D3 version 3?

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to center my bottom **tick label** to be centered.

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
    2018 Oct         2018 Nov        2018 Dec       2019 Jan        2019 Feb
```

There are many [samples online](https://d3fc.io/api/axis-api.html) showing that you can easily obtain that effect by using the method `.tickCenterLabel`.

Unfortunately, it's not working for me (it seems) because the application I'm working on is still using **D3** version 3.

So, is there an equivalent method in version 3, or maybe a different way of obtaining the same effects?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There is no `.tickCenterLabel` method in any version of D3, be it v3, v4 or v5. That method you shared belongs to a D3 plugin.